# Can I prevent stupid errors in JavaScript because the language does not require semicolons?

Tags: javascript

I just lost quite a bit of time because I changed a JavaScript function that read (something like)

```
function F(a,b,c) {

    return x(a,b,c) +
           y(a,b,c) + 
           z(a,b,c);
}
```

to

```
function F(a,b,c) {

    return // x(a,b,c) +
           y(a,b,c) + 
           z(a,b,c);
}
```

when I needed to test something.

The changed function returns `undefined`, of course, because the language does not require a semicolon and assumes the `return` to be a complete statement.

Unfortunatly, when I commented out `x(a,b,c)` I didn't think of this implication. So, is there a way to prevent such stupid misstakes in the future.

Comment: Yep, think of the implication of what you're doing.

Comment: At the risk of being blunt, it sounds like you're ranting since you lost a lot of time on this minor error. Because of that, I think you're already less likely to make it in the future and don't need any special tricks to prevent this.

Comment: You can read about automatic semi-colon insertion: http://es5.github.com/#x7.9

Comment: I *do* unserstand, *why* that happened, I just want to make sure, it doesn't happen *again*.

Comment: I'm not sure it helps with semi-colons, but javascript has a strict mode: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Strict_mode Could help prevent other similar-typed mistakes, maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integrate [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) into your build, and fail builds when you detect

`Problem at line 7 character 12: Unreachable 'y' after 'return'.` Make this generic for line and character, of course. What you're really looking for is "Unreachable after return".

Answer (score 8):

Lazy debugger's solution:

```
function F(a,b,c) {
    return (
      // x(a,b,c) +
      y(a,b,c) + 
      z(a,b,c)
    );
}
```

Comment: I'd still like to see this automated into a build, somehow. Something like "catch all functions that have a return without enclosing parentheses"

Comment: +1 Yep, one reason why I use parens on my return statements.  The interpreter isn't free to decide where the end of my return statement is.

Answer (score 6):

[JSLint](http://JSLint.com) and a unit testing framework.

```
Problem at line 3 character 11: Expected ';' and instead saw 'y'.
```

Answer (score 5):

Semicolon insertion is particularly nasty with `return`. A workaround for this case: don't `return` multiline statements.

```
function F(a,b,c)
{
    var toReturn x(a,b,c) +
           y(a,b,c) + 
           z(a,b,c);

    return toReturn;
}
```

Comment: Automating `process` is one of the main reasons I got into programming, aside from games. If it could theoretically be automated, I had to automate it instead of doing the work by hand. This just seems error prone.

Comment: I thought of that as well at first. But then figured that it would be too much change to existing statements in comparison to just using parens.

Comment: I guess you could probably detect any non-simple return statements that ended with a semi-colon on the same line and fail builds on that. This still feels a little yucky, though.

Comment: Since this is technically detectable, I added a space to your answer so I could upvote it.